# jQuery Uploadify HTTP error (HTTP error: 302)

Tags: php, jquery, forms, upload, uploadify

Uploadify keeps giving me a "HTTP error" and its starting to get pretty annoying.

Here is how I invoke uploadify:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#upload_image').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '/templates/v2/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/userimages.php',
    'cancelImg' : '/templates/v2/images/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : '/images/uploads/1',
    'auto'      : true,
    'fileExt'   : '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
    'fileDesc'  : 'Image Files (.JPG, .GIF, .PNG)',
    'removeCompleted' : false,
    'buttonText' : 'Upload Image'
  });
});

<input id="upload_image" name="userfiles" type="file" />
```

PHP Code:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
$tempFile   = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = '/home/emailsms/app/images/uploads/' . $_SESSION['uid'] . '/';
$targetFile = $targetPath . $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
switch ($_FILES['userfile']['error']) {
    case 0:
        $msg = ""; // comment this out if you don't want a message to appear on success.
        break;
    case 1:
        $msg = "The file is bigger than this PHP installation allows";
        break;
    case 2:
        $msg = "The file is bigger than this form allows";
        break;
    case 3:
        $msg = "Only part of the file was uploaded";
        break;
    case 4:
        $msg = "No file was uploaded";
        break;
    case 6:
        $msg = "Missing a temporary folder";
        break;
    case 7:
        $msg = "Failed to write file to disk";
        break;
    case 8:
        $msg = "File upload stopped by extension";
        break;
    default:
        $msg = "unknown error " . $_FILES['userfile']['error'];
        break;
}

if ($msg) {
    $stringData = "Error: " . $_FILES['userfile']['error'] . " Error Info: " . $msg;
} else {
    $stringData = "1";
} 

echo $stringData;
```

The PHP code works when I use a form:
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/userimages" method="POST">
        Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
    </form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `}` at the end of the file to close `if (!empty($_FILES)) {`

Maybe use a different IDE?

Comment: That's only part of the code. The PHP side works when posted through a regular form.

Comment: Ah ok. I copied your code in a file and did not get the error but I did not send a file. Maybe the problem ist not in this part of the code? You could remove code block by block to find the error.

Comment: I managed to fix this. Turns out there was a problem with the code but also a problem with sessions. I have temporarily disabled sessions on the upload script but I still have to to find a permanent solution for this.